# Streaming microphone input with getUserMedia under iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, getusermedia

I'm developing a website where the user can send audio commands which are captured with getUserMedia (only audio) and interpreted in the backend with a Speech-to-Text service. In order to keep the latency as low as possible, I'm sending small audio chunks to my server. This is working just fine on Chrome/Firefox and even Edge. However, I'm struggling with iOS Safari. I know that Safari is my only choice on Apple devices because of the missing WebRTC support on iOS Chrome/Firefox.

The problem is that I normally get the user's voice a couple of times (for some commands). But without any pattern the stream then suddenly contains only empty bytes. I tried a lot of different strategies but in general I stuck to the following plan:

- After user clicks a button, call getUserMedia (with audio constraint) and save stream to a variable
- Create AudioContext (incl. Gain, MediaStreamSource, ScriptProcess) and connect the audio stream to the MediaStreamSource
- Register an event listener to the ScriptProcessor and send audio chunks in callback to the server
- When a result is returned from the server close AudioContext and audio's MediaStream

The interesting part is now what happens after a subsequent user command. I tried various things: Call getUserMedia again for each call and close the MediaStream track each time, use the initially created MediaStream and reconnect the EventHandler every time, close the AudioContext after every call, use only one initially created AudioContext... All my attempts failed so far, because I either got empty bytes from the Stream or the AudioContext was created in a "suspended" state. Only closing MediaStream/AudioContext and creating it every time again seems to be more stable, but fetching the MediaStream with getUserMedia takes quite a while on iOS (~1,5-2s), which gives a bad user experience.
I'll show you my latest attempt where I tried to mute/disable the stream in between user commands and keep the AudioContext open:

```
var audioStream: MediaStream;
var audioContext: AudioContext;

var startButton = document.getElementById("startButton");
startButton.onclick = () => {
    if (!audioStream) {
        getUserAudioStream();
    } else {
        // mute/disable stream
        audioStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = true; 
    }
}

var stopButton = document.getElementById("stopButton");
stopButton.onclick = () => {
    // unmute/enable stream
    audioStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false;
}

function getUserAudioStream(): Promise<any> {
    return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true
        } as MediaTrackConstraints,
    }).then((stream: MediaStream) => {
        audioStream = stream;
        startRecording();
    }).catch((e) => { ... });
}

const startRecording = () => {
    const ctx = (window as any).AudioContext || (window as any).webkitAudioContext;
    if (!ctx) {
        console.error("No Audio Context available in browser.");
        return;
    } else {
        audioContext = new ctx();
    }

    const inputPoint = audioContext.createGain();
    const microphone = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(audioStream);
    scriptProcessor = inputPoint.context.createScriptProcessor(4096, 1, 1);

    microphone.connect(inputPoint);
    inputPoint.connect(scriptProcessor);
    scriptProcessor.connect(inputPoint.context.destination);

    scriptProcessor.addEventListener("audioprocess", streamCallback);
};

const streamCallback = (e) => {
    const samples = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);

    // Here I stream audio chunks to the server and 
    // observe that buffer sometimes only contains empty bytes...
}
```

I hope the snippet makes sense to you, because I let some stuff out to keep it readable. I think I made clear that this is only one of many attempts and actually my question is: Is there some kind of special characteristic in WebRTC/getUserMedia on iOS that I missed so far? Why does iOS treat MediaStream differently than Chrome/Firefox on Windows? As a last comment: I know that the ScriptProcessorNode is no longer recommended. Actually, I'd like to use MediaRecorder for that but this is also not yet supported on iOS. Also, the polyfill I know is not really suitable because it only support ogg for streaming audio and which also leads to problems because I would need to set the sample rate for that to a fixed value.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have a related problem, where the user has to shout to the microphone with Safari on Mac and iPad, whereas there are no problems with Firefox and Edge on Mac.

Comment: @PalleM.Pedersen Unfortunately not really. I ended up using a Polyfill [opus-media-recorder](https://github.com/kbumsik/opus-media-recorder). If I remember correctly, they use more or less the same approach, but it works stable to a certain extent. Maybe you can give that a try.